# Exporting game made in Unity3d using accelerometer features and database to mobile ? Possible?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, export, accelerometer

So, I have to do an app to my company, my first job, and I have to use the accelerometer, in this case to calculate the movement that the player is doing.

I have to implement for iOS and Android but I have few time to do it.

I found Unity3d, but I would like to know:

Is it going to work for iOS and Android if I export?

How can I update the app using Unity3d?

Is the app the same after the exportation?

Can I implement the accelerometer one time, or I have to do 2 different times, to iOS and to Android?

Another question: is the Database implementation going to be the same?

Thank you so much. I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making an app just for accelerometer, it'd be a lot faster to do it in Java and Objective-C respectively, than to figure out Unity3D, which is actually a game engine.

Of course all of the things you've mentioned are possible in Unity, but it's not made for apps, at least not a simple 2D or UI based app.

Comment: " but it's not made for apps, at least not a simple 2D or UI based app." what do you mean ? You mean that it is easier to program to iOS and Android separately? I dont know both, so I would learn both.What do you recommend for just 4 months?

Comment: 4 months are enough for making an accelerometer app even if you don't know anything. It depends upon what you're really trying to do. There're examples available for both platforms

Comment: Thank you. :) I will try to do separately so.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes

2) Open Unity, update your app, build for both platforms and then push to their respective stores.

3) They will almost be identical.

4) You "should" only have to write it once, but you might need to do some conditionals depending on what you are doing, or what bugs come up on the different systems.

Comment: SO, do you recommend using Unity3d instead of programming to 2 different platforms?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.

Comment: I have to use Databse, but the accelerometer part It is very simple.

Comment: So you are not making a video game? Because that is why you use unity.

Comment: It is and game. I have to calculate when the person is running and get the distance using accelerometer. I have to keep the points in a DBase.